# How to create a Spring Reactor Flux from Http integration flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a question very similar to this one [How to create a Spring Reactor Flux from a ActiveMQ queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126775/how-to-create-a-spring-reactor-flux-from-a-activemq-queue)

With one difference that messages come from Http endpoint rather than JMS queue. The problem is that Message Channel is not get populated for some reason or it is not picked up by Flux.from(). The log entries show that GenericMessage is created from Http Integration flow with a payload as path variable but does not get enqueued/published to a channel? I tried `.channel(MessageChannels.queue())` and `.channel(MessageChannels.publishSubscribe())`
does not make any difference, event stream is empty. Here is the code:

```
@Bean
public Publisher<Message<String>> httpReactiveSource() {
        return IntegrationFlows.
                from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("/eventmessage/{id}")
                        .requestMapping(r -> r
                        .methods(HttpMethod.POST)                                                                                   
                        )
                        .payloadExpression("#pathVariables.id")
                        )                           
                        .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                        .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)                            
                        .log()  
                        .toReactivePublisher();
    }


@GetMapping(value="eventmessagechannel/{id}", produces=MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> eventMessages(@PathVariable String id){     
    return Flux.from(httpReactiveSource())              
            .map(Message::getPayload);

}
```

UPDATE1:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration') 
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux') 
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')

}
```

UPDATE2

It works when `@SpringBootApplication` and `@RestController` are defined in one file, but stops to work when `@SpringBootApplication` and `@RestController` are in separate files.

TestApp.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
package com.example.controller;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.channel.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.http.dsl.Http;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;



import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;



@RestController
public class TestController {
     @Bean
        public Publisher<Message<String>> httpReactiveSource() {
            return IntegrationFlows.
                    from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("/message/{id}")
                            .requestMapping(r -> r
                                    .methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                            )
                            .payloadExpression("#pathVariables.id")
                    )
                    .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                    .toReactivePublisher();
        }

        @GetMapping(value = "/events", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
        public Flux<String> eventMessages() {
            return Flux.from(httpReactiveSource())
                    .map(Message::getPayload);
        }

}
```

Comment: What Spring Boot configuration (`pom`) do you use? How do you mix Servlet container with the WebFlux ?

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you for looking into it. I am trying it with all defaults of `SpringBootApplication v. '2.0.0.M2'`. I have a `@RestController` with above mentioned two methods. And it is basically all the same (config-wise) like in your answer in the ActiveMQ topic which works for me. But instead of JMS queue I receive message from http REST call.

Comment: I have just updated the question with gradle dependencies being used. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the update. I see that you have both `web` and `webflux` dependencies. How does it work just with `web`? I can't check locally because Boot is broken a bit now

Comment: Thank you for getting back. Ok, created a new quick project and removed dependency on `spring-boot-starter-webflux` in it. But looks like it did not help. Still, no events are being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me well:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringIntegrationSseDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationSseDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Publisher<Message<String>> httpReactiveSource() {
        return IntegrationFlows.
                from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("/message/{id}")
                        .requestMapping(r -> r
                                .methods(HttpMethod.POST)
                        )
                        .payloadExpression("#pathVariables.id")
                )
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                .toReactivePublisher();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/events", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> eventMessages() {
        return Flux.from(httpReactiveSource())
                .map(Message::getPayload);
    }

}
```

I have this dependencies in POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I run the app and have two terminals:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/events
```

to listen to SSEs.

And in the second one I perform this:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/message/foo

curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/message/bar

curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/message/666
```

So, the first terminal responds like:

```
data:foo

data:bar

data:666
```

Note, we don't need `spring-boot-starter-webflux` dependency. The `Flux` to SSE works well with regular MVC on the Servlet Container.

Spring Integration will support WebFlux soon, too: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4300. So, you will be able to configure there something like:

```
   IntegrationFlows
    .from(Http.inboundReactiveGateway("/sse")
                        .requestMapping(m -> m.produces(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)))
```

And fully rely just only WebFlux without any Servlet Container dependencies.

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you for your efforts on it again as well as explanations. Your code works and it has helped to narrow it down  to the fact that for some reason of being `@SpringBootApplication` and `@RestController` defined in one file makes it working but when they are in separate files (which is actually sounds more like a real-life case) it does not.

Comment: Look, the problem is with a missed `@Configuration` on that your `TestController`. Right, the `httpReactiveSource()` `@Bean` is processed and registered properly thanks to the "light configuration" mechanism. But since you call `httpReactiveSource()` method directly from the `eventMessages()` method, there is no proxy call and the `httpReactiveSource()` doesn't delegate to the bean factory for the proper bean resolution. So, really consider to move  `httpReactiveSource()` definition to the `@Configuration` class and use `@Autowired` in the `TestController` for the `Publisher<Message<String>>`.

Comment: That was it, Artem! It works now when defined via `@Configuration`. We have got to the bottom of the problem finally! Thanks! You guys are doing an awesome job on this framework!