# Server Sent Events using Spring WebFlux, EventSource and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, server-sent-events, spring-webflux, eventsource

I want to create live notifications for my website.

Reference link: http://sinhamohit.com/writing/spring-boot-reactive-sse

Above link contains example for SSE and Event Source. The stream of objects is created to create Flux stream.

In my case, I want to create server sent events and send them to RabbitMQ server, the rest controller should be able to listen to message queue and receive the message.

Right now I am able to receive the messages, but I am not sure how I can convert them into Flux and send the stream to rest URL.

How should I do it?
Refernces, links and examples will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126775/how-to-create-a-spring-reactor-flux-from-a-activemq-queue), here activemq is used but you can also use RabbitMQ.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.